# Верстка сайтов

Tags: pdf, html, вёрстка, css

Здравствуйте! Хочу верстать. Полазив в интернете, нашел много мусора. Может кто-нибудь знает видео курсы о верстке сайтов по макету `pdf`?

Comment: "о верстке pdf сайтов"? Не уверен, что понимаю вопрос :(

Comment: сайт в формате PDF? вы его печатать собрались? попробуйте с HTML начать

Comment: Опечатался, неужели меня не поняли? верстка с PDF в html&css

Comment: нету нечего веселого в верстке =) как это нечего не нашел?)

Comment: Мнеб видеоуроки, желательно не сильно старые, те кто уже верстал/верстает без проблем что нибуть подкинут

Answer (score 3):

Привет!) Советую начинать с http://htmlbook.ru/, Затем найти пару бесплатных psd макетов и практиковаться. Делай их на совесть по всем стандартам и кроссбраузерно. Самое быстрый способ научиться верстать, это практиковаться и практиковаться. Вопросы которые будут возникать задавай здесь, здесь тебе всегда будут рады;)

Answer (score 2):

Собственно, как учился я: мне давали готовые проекты в psd (собственно, в нормальных фирмах, так и делается). Тут главное понять, как резать их и желательно знать фотошоп. Соответственно, если правильно разрежете, подогнать все на html - не проблема.

Answer (score 2):

Видимо все же не PDF, а PSD :)

Вам нужны не видео-уроки, а литература которой в интернете много.

- понять предназначение HTML тэгов
- понять CSS
- понимать разницу между блочными и строковыми элементами
- иметь представление о потоке элементов
- иметь представление о элементах вырванных из потока (float, position, etc.)
- представлять себе как можно позиционировать элементы относительно друг-друга
- попрактиковаться с разбивкой PSD макета на нужную графику

А дальше все придет только с практикой. После пары десятков макетов поймете и как лучше организовать свой layout сайта и как лучше графику подготовить.

Видео-уроки что дадут?  Какой-то дядя монотонным голосом расскажет как написать 3 блока и расположить одни над другим?  Без теоретических знаний это мало чем поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Советую скачать курсы по версте HTML & CSS от СПЕЦИАЛИСТА, не пожалеете! Есть на [rutraker.org](http://rutraker.org) и вот [тут](http://nnm-club.ru/forum/tracker.php) очень много курсов Специалиста. Введите в поиске "**Специалист Html**".

Comment: Плюс Вы путаете файл PSD (Photoshop макет) с файлом PDF.

Comment: Я, все же, считаю, что надо самому читать спецификацию перед просмотром видеокурсов. Что для кого-то СПЕЦИАЛИСТ для другого человека может оказаться "специалист". Прежде надо разобраться в том как верстать, а потом смотреть видео других людей и думать почему так делают, а не иначе (но надо понимать как бы ты сам сделал иначе). А если сразу смотреть, то просто запомнишь как делает кто-то (без личного мнения на решение этой задачи) и не факт, что этот кто-то делает данную работу лучшим способом.

Comment: Я не верстальщик, но курсы от Специалиста мне очень понравились, объясняет преподаватель очень понятно + рассматриваются вопросы верстки под старые браузеры (IE6 и другие). Просмотр явно лишним не будет. Также преподаватель объясняет как правильно работать со спецификацией W3C.
З.Ы. ТС как раз попросил видео уроки, поэтому я и посоветовал уроки Специалиста!